# Route 53 as backup to Cloudflare DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53, cloudflare

I use cloudflare as my main DNS provider right now but am looking to add route 53 as another provider/backup in case one or the other goes down. (DYN did this last year and it caused a headache with just one provider)

It is my understanding that I need to add the NS records to each domain and then update the name servers for each domain with my domain register.

Is this the best way to ensure uptime? Are there any issues with this?

Comment: Are you using CloudFlare as a CDN (orange cloud) or just a DNS provider (gray cloud)? If you use Route53 would you be using the AWS CDN, CloudFront, or just Route53?

Comment: Two useful links for you to study: [one](http://blog.serverfault.com/2017/01/09/surviving-the-next-dns-attack/), [two](https://github.com/StackExchange/dnscontrol/).

Comment: I've just implemented dnscontrol for all of my domains, and it's super slick.

Comment: Before you mitigate the DNS risk, is your application highly available? Do you have any single points of failure? Do you have geographically distributed servers? If not I would focus on that first, as it's probably more vulnerable than a well managed, well distributed system like CloudFlare.

Comment: I am using cloudflare with mostly gray cloud and some orange cloud for some caching on main site but not on most of traffic for application due to timeouts with long requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend reading the two links that [EEAA commented](https://serverfault.com/questions/847647/route-53-as-backup-to-cloudflare-dns#comment1087418_847647), along with a third:

- [How Stack Overflow plans to survive the next DNS attack](http://blog.serverfault.com/2017/01/09/surviving-the-next-dns-attack/)
- [Introducing DnsControl – "DNS as Code" has Arrived](http://blog.serverfault.com/2017/04/11/introducing-dnscontrol-dns-as-code-has-arrived/)
- [DNS Control on GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/dnscontrol/)

Essentially you have the right idea. Specify your additional nameservers as NS records in both of your zones (Route 53 and Cloudflare), and then add those new nameservers to your registrars configuration for your domain.

There will be zero downtime if you do this correctly.

The way to ensure you do this correctly is to use a tool like Stack Exchange's DNS Control to make the changes for you. Get it working with your current single DNS provider, and then just throw in the config to tell DNS Control to send the zone to multiple providers.

Note: I just saw in the comments that you are using orange-cloud with CloudFlare. An orange-cloud setup is totally incompatible with 3rd party DNS providers, as CloudFlare manipulates your served DNS records. This will only work for grey-cloud sites.

Don't let that put you off DNS Control though, as DNS Control has support for orange cloud control (just don't use dual DNS providers with orange cloud)

Comment: @ChrisMuench Feel free to give it a +1 then :)